# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

When I try to load my rails app on my localhost I get an error telling me to resolve it by running `rails db:migrate` but when I try to run the command this is what I get

```
C:\Sites\CoolGuyGear>rails db:migrate

== 20180108004216 AddDeviseToViews: migrating =================================
-- change_table(:views)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email: ALTER TABLE "views" ADD "email" varchar DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
C:/Sites/CoolGuyGear/db/migrate/20180108004216_add_devise_to_views.rb:7:in `block in up'
C:/Sites/CoolGuyGear/db/migrate/20180108004216_add_devise_to_views.rb:5:in `up'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email: ALTER TABLE "views" ADD "email" varchar DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
C:/Sites/CoolGuyGear/db/migrate/20180108004216_add_devise_to_views.rb:7:in `block in up'
C:/Sites/CoolGuyGear/db/migrate/20180108004216_add_devise_to_views.rb:5:in `up'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Caused by:
SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email
C:/Sites/CoolGuyGear/db/migrate/20180108004216_add_devise_to_views.rb:7:in `block in up'
C:/Sites/CoolGuyGear/db/migrate/20180108004216_add_devise_to_views.rb:5:in `up'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Migration:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class AddDeviseToViews < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def self.up
    change_table :views do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      # Uncomment below if timestamps were not included in your original model.
      # t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :views, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :views, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :views, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :views, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end

  def self.down
    # By default, we don't want to make any assumption about how to roll  
    #back a migration when your
    # model already existed. Please edit below which fields you would like to remove in this migration.
  raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end


 create_table "views", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_views_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: 
"index_views_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
 end
```

Comment: post that migration file db/migrate/20180108004216_add_devise_to_views.rb. that's where the error is

Comment: yeah, the error is about that file on line 5 and 7 but can't figure out which lines are those.

Comment: can you please append the `views` table from `db/schema.rb` in your question? If you don't get a clue from @Trenton's answer, then this will help others figure out your issue. Thanks

Comment: @WasifHossain I added the table

Comment: thats the migration; I am interested what the `views` table looks like in `db/schema.rb`, not the migration file under `db/migrate/`. Thanks

Comment: I added it at the bottom of the migration file, dont know why it formatted like that but it is there

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in the question.

Whatever migrations you have added are creating duplicate columns in your database as seen in the log generated from the migration.

`duplicate column name: email: ALTER TABLE "views" ADD "email"`

Create a migration that either removes those columns from your database or go directly into your local mysql/sqlite database and remove those columns manually. Run the migration again and, since you don't already have those columns in your database table, you will not receive these errors.